# Design view is unavailable for x64 and ARM target platforms in windows phone 8.1 app

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

My Design View is not showing even though I change my architecture to x86 or Any CPU as shown in image

[image]

Need help stuck here for a long time . I also restart the Visual Studio but unable to do so.

Comment: clean/Rebuild the solution. This often helps to fix such strange issues.